# Using Stone-Weierstrass theorem prove that $f\equiv 0$ in $[0,1]$ under certain conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, polynomials, weierstrass-approximation

> Let $f$ be a continuous function over $[0,1]$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=0$. If for any positive integer $n$, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{12+3n}f(x)\,dx=0$ then using Stone-Weiersterass Theorem prove that $f\equiv 0$ in $[0,1]$.

Since $f$ is contnuous on $[0,1]$ so by Stone-Weierstrass Theorem there exists a sequence of polynomials $\{p_n(x)\}_n$ which converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$.  That is  , $p_n\to f$ , implies  $p_n(x)f(x)\to f^2(x)$ as $n\to \infty$, which implies that $\displaystyle \int_0^1p_n(x)f(x)\,dx \to \int_0^1 f^2(x)\,dx$. But from the given condition I can't say that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f^2(x)\,dx =0$. So how to proceed to solve this problem ? Any hint. please.

Comment: Try to apply Stone-Weierstrass with not all the polynomials, but just the polynomials of a certain form.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Not getting the point. Can I get hint a little more ?

Comment: Stone-Weierstrass theorem gives that under some conditions, a subset of $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ is dense. What you know (and what you wanted to use) is that Stone-Weierstrass can be applied with the subset of all polynomial functions. But you can also try to apply it with *another* subset, maybe smaller than all the polynomials, which would also satisfy the conditions of Stone-Weierstrass, and hence, would be dense...

Answer (score 1):

The span of the monomials $\{1\} \cup \{x^{3n+12} : n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ because
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{3n+12} = \frac13 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n+4} = \frac13 \sum_{n=5}^\infty \frac1n = +\infty$$

so the [Müntz–Szász theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem) gives the conclusion.

Now approximate $f$ by polynomials from $\operatorname{span}(\{1\} \cup \{x^{3n+12} : n\in\Bbb{N}\})$.

Answer (score 1):

Setting  $g(x)=x^{12}f(x)$,  we know that
$$
  \int_0^1 x^{3n}g(x)\,dx=0,
  $$
for every $n>0$, and hence also
$$
  \int_0^1 p(x^3)g(x)\,dx=0,
  $$
for every polynomial $p$ with vanishing constant term.  Since the set of functions of the form $p(x^3)$, with $p(0)=0$,
is a dense subalgebra of
$$
  C_0((0,1]) = \{h∈   C([0,1]): h(0)=0\}
  $$
by Stone-Weierstrass, we deduce that   $\int_0^1 h(x)g(x)\,dx=0$, for all $h$ in that subalgebra, so $g=0$ on $(0,1]$.

Consequently $f=0$ on $(0,1]$ as well and, since $f$ is continuous, we  conclude that $f$ vanishes everywhere.